# Trigger a slide right animation after rendering a component through history.push

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this  component that redirects the user upon a click, to another path, associated with a component.

```
        return (
          <Item
            key={id}
            onClick={() =>
            history.push({
                    pathname: '/path/login',
                    state: {
                      requiredAction: name,
                    },
                  })
            }
            description={description}
          />
        );
```

my login component as follows:

```
export default withRouter(function FormCard(props) {

  let { location } = props;

  return (
    <div className="text-center">

      {location.state.imageData && (
        <Image className={location.state.imageData} />
      )}

      <div className="heading mb-5 pt-2">
          <FormattedMessage defaultMessage="Access your  account" />
        )}
      </div>


      <div>
        <input
          className="email-form"
          type="email"
          inputMode="email"
          onChange={changeEmail}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Route is defined as follows:

```
  <Route
     exact
     path="/path/login"
     render={() => <FormCard {...this.props} />}
   />
```

==========================

Is is possible that I add some logic on `history.push`, after the initial click that triggers an animation to slide right the login component, instead of simply displaying it?

Comment: You could use CSS Animation to make it slide right on loading, or do something similar in your component logic. I

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add some logic on `history.push`. I suggest that you listen in your `/path/login` for the passed state, like this:

Example Component (In your case the /path/login one):

```js
const App = (props) => {
  const {location} = props;
  
  useEffect(()=>{
  
  if(location.state.PASSED_VAL){
    // Do something 
  }
  },[location.state])
}

return (...)


}
```